# Trying to list entries related to users with a specific category selected

Tags: entries, relations, category

This is a category page. I am trying to display all entries from users with this specific category selected in their account (user field that is a category field type.) This is the code I have so far, but it is not returning results. No errors - just not returning anything unfortunately:

```
<h1>{{ category.title }}</h1>

{# Grab all the users who have this category selected (which is a 'category field type' user field) #}
{% set categoryUsers = craft.users.relatedTo(category).limit(null) %}

{# Grab all of the entries by those users #}    
{% set categoryUserEntries = craft.entries.section('jobs').relatedTo(categoryUsers).limit(null) %}

{% paginate categoryUserEntries.limit(8) as entries %}

     {% for entry in entries %} 
         <h1><a href="{{ entry.url }}">{{ entry.title }}</a></h1>
     {% endfor %}

     {% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}" class="pagination left">&laquo; Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
     {% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}" class="pagination right">Next Page &raquo;</a>{% endif %}

{% endpaginate %}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Add a `{{ categoryUserEntries|length }}` before the pagination part. Does that return anything?

Comment: This returned '0' although it should return 1 because  1 user has this category selected in the category user field. Testing the first variable - {{ categoryUsers|length }} -  does give the correct amount so it looks like this is an issue with the way the 'relatedTo' is working for this.

Answer (score 1):

I think I worked this out. It looks like the related entries need to be contained in the user loop. This is what I used to make this work:

```
{% set categoryUsers = craft.users.relatedTo(category) %}
    {% paginate categoryUsers.limit(1) as entries %}

        {% for categoryUser in entries %}
            {{ categoryUser.username }}

            {% set categoryEntry = craft.entries.section('jobs').authorId(categoryUser.id).first() %}       
                {% if categoryEntry %}
                    {{ categoryEntry.positionTitle }} (And other fields not added yet.)
                {% endif %}

             <p>Testing the total found: {{ categoryUsers|length }}</p>
        {% endfor %}

    {% if paginate.prevUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.prevUrl }}" class="pagination left">&laquo; Previous Page</a>{% endif %}
    {% if paginate.nextUrl %}<a href="{{ paginate.nextUrl }}" class="pagination right">Next Page &raquo;</a>{% endif %}

    {% endpaginate %}
```

Still testing, but I think this is the solution. (Unless someone else has a better way of doing this. :))